# continuation of thread connected with system of congruences

Tags: systems-of-equations, congruences

[System of 3 linear congruences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/system-of-3-linear-congruences)
I read this subject and I have doubts.

1. Why $x\equiv 25 \pmod{7^2} \implies x\equiv 4\pmod {7} $ ?
2. $x\equiv 399\pmod{1089}$ Is equivalent to system: $x \equiv 399 \pmod{11^2}; \ \ \ x \equiv 399 \pmod {3^2} $
3. Is it true that:
   $$\begin{cases} x\equiv 39 \mod(189) \\ x\equiv 25 \mod(539) \\ x\equiv 399 \mod(1089) \end{cases}  \iff \begin{cases}x\equiv 39\pmod{3^3}\\ x\equiv 39\pmod{7}\\ x\equiv 25\pmod{11} \\  x\equiv 25\pmod{7^2}\\  x\equiv 399\pmod{11^2} \\  x\equiv 399\pmod{3^2}  \end{cases}   $$

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $ab\mid x$ then both $a\mid x$ and $b\mid x$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: So, what do you actually know about congruences, xawey? Do you know that $a\equiv b\pmod c$ means $b-a$ is a multiple of $c$? Do you know that if $x\equiv a\pmod bc$ then $x\equiv a\pmod b$? Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: So when it comes to 1. $x\equiv 25 \pmod{7^2} \implies x\equiv 25 \pmod{7}\iff x\equiv 4\pmod {7} $ What about 3? is it ok ?

Comment: 3 looks OK to me.